# Parallax Positioning Problems Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, parallax

I am learning how to do Parallax and Bootstrap 4 and I am having issues having the result of this website: [Sample Website](http://www.lornehubdesign.com/)

On his website, the homepage is the same size on all platforms, laptop | Desktop | Mobile, etc..
I am trying to get the same result but I am having very much issues on achieving it. I do not know its proper name which is why I am asking Overflow because if I do not know what it is properly called or how to describe it, how can I get a relative search result? Please help and don't hate on me for probably easy question, I am still new to this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the containing div of that topmost section you could set the height to

```
.exampleContainer{
    height:100vh;
}
```

vh stands for 'viewport height' 
if you wanted to for width you could use 100vw for 'viewport width' instead of 100%

you might need to account for the height of the navbar so your css could look something like this...

```
.exampleNavbar{
    height: 5rem;
}

.exampleContainer{
    height: calc(100vh - 5rem);
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying @Chulps ! This works fantastically! I set the Navigation Bar to Fixed as that was the point to originally. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hey @Chulps I have another question for you, if you look at the website I referenced in my original post, how does he keep all of the content where they belong like you're looking at the desktop version? I've been trying to solve for that reason but I can not figure it out

Comment: position: static; ?

it's hard to say without seeing some code

Comment: I have fixed the content issue, I have introduced Media Queries into the CSS and using Chromes device emulator, I have fixed all apparent issues with mobile interaction